# ios - WKWebView evaluateJavaScript not scrolling to fragment identifier

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview, fragment-identifier

I am trying to navigate to a fragment identifier in a webpage in `WKWebView`. To do this, I have the following call in my `WKNavigationDelegate`'s `didFinishNavigation`:

```
[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"window.location.hash = 'hash';" 
completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
    NSLog(@"Result %@",result);
}];
```

The webpage did not scroll to the fragment. When I connected the Safari developer console to my ios device simulator for debugging, I could see that window.location.hash was set to the hash. Manually setting the hash in the developer console would not cause the `WKWebView` to scroll either.

At first I thought it was the `javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically` property of `WKPreferences` that was preventing me from manipulating the javascript `window` object, but even after setting that to true it wasn't working.

Does anyone know what's going on?

---

**EDIT:** The issue is that the webpage is dynamically loaded, and the fragment identifier that I am trying to jump to doesn't exist unless I scroll all the way to the bottom. For now, my work around is to scroll all the way down using javascript, and then go to the hash fragment identifier.

**Anyone have a smarter solution?**

Comment: 2 notes: 1: You need to include the `#` in order for it to scroll. So, for example, you'd need to write `'#hash'` instead of just `'hash'`. 2: The new hash needs to be different from the old one for scrolling to happen. Maybe try setting it to an empty string immediately before this?